# How to do this query in mongo: get newest messages for a list of users

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have a collection of messages with fields user_id, created_time, and content. Given a list of user_id, I would like to get back a list of messages, where for each user_id it contains a message newest with respect to that user. I thought about using a distinct command together with sort in mongo but that doesn't seem to be supported. Is there a way to do this in mongo using a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has the [Aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) which you can use for tasks that require some manipulation of your data in your collection

Consider the following dataset

```
> db.messages.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecb77486d35a12f3552aa1"),
    "user_id" : "fred",
    "create_date" : ISODate("1392-09-21T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecb79286d35a12f3552aa2"),
    "user_id" : "fred",
    "create_date" : ISODate("1392-06-01T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecb7a386d35a12f3552aa3"),
    "user_id" : "marty",
    "create_date" : ISODate("1393-04-06T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ecb7af86d35a12f3552aa4"),
    "user_id" : "marty",
    "create_date" : ISODate("1386-02-12T00:00:00Z")
}
```

So in passing this to aggregate we want to group on `user_id` and get the most recent or `maximum` create_date

```
> db.messages.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { user_id: "$user_id" }, create_date: {  $max: "$create_date" }} }
  ])
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : "marty"
                    },
                    "create_date" : ISODate("1393-04-06T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : {
                            "user_id" : "fred"
                    },
                    "create_date" : ISODate("1392-09-21T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

That's not bad but you can clean it up with **$project**

```
> db.messages.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: { user_id: "$user_id" }, create_date: {  $max: "$create_date" }} },
    { $project: {  _id: 0, user_id: "$_id.user_id", create_date: 1} }
  ])
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "create_date" : ISODate("1393-04-06T00:00:00Z"),
                    "user_id" : "marty"
            },
            {
                    "create_date" : ISODate("1392-09-21T00:00:00Z"),
                    "user_id" : "fred"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So that actually looks like a clean record to use. In latest drivers the returned value from aggregate should be a cursor you can iterate over. So the results are just the same to work with as using find.

Additional documentation on operators to use can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to also include the content field (for the latest message) in the result?

Comment: Yes. Just follow the example and documentation and add your fields.

Comment: @dementrock: if you want to get the latest content as well as the create date, you could add an initial `{$sort:{create_date: -1}}` pipeline step and then use the [`$first` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to find the most recent values of `content` and `create_date` per group. Note: I'm using `$first` because I sorted by `create_date` descending, but if you sort by date ascending then `$last` works similarly.